# XPath to find nodes having 2 leaf children

Tags: xml, xpath

I have an XML like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Math mode="inline" tex="\tilde{p}_{d}\leq\tilde{p}_{d+1}" text="(tilde@(p)) _ d less= (tilde@(p)) _ (d + 1)">
    <RMath>
        <RApp>
            <RTok meaning="less-than-or-equals" name="leq" role="RELOP">?</RTok>
            <RApp>
                <RTok role="SUBSCRIPTOP" scriptpos="post2"/>
                <RApp>
                    <RTok name="tilde" role="OVERACCENT" stretchy="false">~</RTok>
                    <RTok role="UNKNOWN" font="italic">p</RTok>
                </RApp>
                <RTok role="UNKNOWN" font="italic">d</RTok>
            </RApp>
            <RApp>
                <RTok role="SUBSCRIPTOP" scriptpos="post2"/>
                <RApp>
                    <RTok name="tilde" role="OVERACCENT" stretchy="false">~</RTok>
                    <RTok role="UNKNOWN" font="italic">p</RTok>
                </RApp>
                <RApp>
                    <RTok meaning="plus" role="ADDOP">+</RTok>
                    <RTok role="UNKNOWN" font="italic">d</RTok>
                    <RTok meaning="1" role="NUMBER">1</RTok>
                </RApp>
            </RApp>
        </RApp>
    </RMath>
</Math>
```

I want to use XPath to extract the nodes which have 2 children where the 2 children are leaf nodes such as:

```
<RApp>
      <RTok name="tilde" role="OVERACCENT" stretchy="false">~</RTok>
      <RTok role="UNKNOWN" font="italic">p</RTok>
</RApp>
```

I can not think of the appropriate predicates for this extraction.

I know that `.//*[not(child::*)]` find all the leaf nodes.

and `//*[not(child::*) and (ancestor-or-self::XMApp)]` will find all leaf nodes with ancestor tag `RApp`.

I do not want the node (RApp) but just want its children? i.e. any 2 leaf sibling that does not have any other sibling.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: `.//*[count(child::) = 2]` ?

Comment: this one did not work. thanks for trying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below to get desirable output:

```
//RApp[count(child::*)=2 and count(child::RTok)=2]
```

This will return `RApp` elements with 2 children if both child elements are `RTok`

Comment: Why unaccepted? You need some solution improvement?

Comment: sorry I am confused with this acceptance. I just think using .//*[not(*/*) and count(*) = 2] would be better as it works with any XML with different tag names. And yes I would like improvement please as with this one what if I do not want the node (RApp) but just want its children?  i.e. any 2 leaf sibling that does not have any other sibling.

Comment: I means I want the nodes that have no children and they are only 2 sibling. so in my example I want <RTok name="tilde" role="OVERACCENT" stretchy="false">~</RTok>
      <RTok role="UNKNOWN" font="italic">p</RTok> without their parent node which is <RApp>

Comment: Can you try `//*[count(child::*)=2 and count(descendant::*)=2]/*` and let me know if it works as expected?

Comment: Sorry, I thought I replied to you. Yes it works as I need. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`.//*[not(*/*) and count(*) = 2]` is the more readable I can think of for:

- Any node
- That has no great-children
- That has exactly 2 child

Seems to be your "Nodes having 2 leaf children".

For the curiosity, `.//*[count(.//*[not(*)]) = 2]` would match "Nodes that has exactly 2 descendant [children and sub-children] that are leafs"

Comment: your first xpath expression very good that does not use tag name so could work with any xml file. but what if I do not want the node (RApp) but just want its children? i.e any leaf 2 sibling

Comment: any leaf 2 sibling that does not have any other sibling

Comment: Got quite some troubles understanding your request (hence the delay), but if you want to select the great children, just add `/*/*` so `.//*[not(*/*) and count(*) = 2]/*/*` (stars can be turned into more narrowed selector, like `RApp` or `RTok` depending on what you want to match)